# Geom_bar: how to reorder bars to be in descending order

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am working with data on scores of universities, and have a grouped horizontal bar graph showing the respective ratings for each college. However, I'd like to make my bars go in descending order - how do I do this?

Code:

```
ratings <- read.csv("senior_expert_ratings_tall.csv", stringsAsFactors = T)
```

```
ggplot(data=ratings, aes(x=Assessment,y=Rating,fill=Agency)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity") + 
  labs(title="Expert Ratings of Key Universities",
       subtitle="The INORMS Research Evaluation Group, in partnership with rankings\nexpert Dr Richard Holmes, produced a rating of six key global university\nrankings in 2021. Using 20 community-sourced criteria across four main\nthemes (good governance, rigour, transparency, and measure what matters)\nexperts were invited to assess the ranking agencies both qualitatively and\nquantitatively. The assessment found that all rankers fell short of the community\nexpectations, with the higher-profile agencies faring worse than others.",
       caption = "Figure 2: Global university ranking agencies assessed by international experts\nagainst criteria including transparency and rigour.") +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust=0)) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(size=8)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[Output graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9OrS.png)

Comment: Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(ratings)`.

Comment: You could use `reorder`. You can see an example [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/ggplot-barplot-in-decending-order/31126/2)